# Using recursive CTE to calculate expiration dates of contracts in SQL Server with gaps in between?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL task to return this output.

```
SubID,FromDT,ToDT,ContractEndDT,ContractPeriod,MonthTowardExpiration
1,2014-01-01,2014-02-01,2015-01-01, 12, 12
1,2014-02-01,2014-03-01,2015-01-01, 12, 11
1, 2014-03-01, 2014-04-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 10
1, 2014-04-01, 2014-05-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 9
1, 2014-05-01, 2014-06-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 8
1, 2014-06-01, 2014-07-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 7
1, 2014-07-01, 2014-08-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 6
1, 2014-08-01, 2014-09-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 5
1, 2014-09-01, 2014-10-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 4
1, 2014-10-01, 2014-11-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 3
1, 2014-11-01, 2014-12-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 2
1, 2014-12-01, 2015-01-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 1
1, 2015-01-01, 2015-02-01, 2015-01-01, 12, 0
1, 2015-02-01, 2015-03-01, 2015-01-01, 12, -1
1, 2015-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2015-01-01, 12, -2
1, 2015-04-01, 2015-05-01, 2015-01-01, 12, -3
1, 2015-05-01, 2015-06-01, 2015-01-01, 12, -4
1, 2015-06-01, 2015-07-01, 2015-01-01, 12, -5
1, 2015-07-01, 2015-08-01, 2015-01-01, 12, -6
1, 2015-08-01, 2015-09-01, 2017-08-01, 24, 24
1, 2015-09-01, 2015-10-01, 2017-08-01, 24, 23
1, 2015-10-01, 2015-11-01, 2017-08-01, 24, 22
1, 2015-11-01, 2015-12-01, 2017-08-01, 24, 21
1, 2015-12-01, 2016-01-01, 2017-08-01, 24, 20
```

Based on the following table:

```
SubID, StartDT, EndDT, ContractEndDT, ContractPeriod
1, 2014-01-01, 2015-08-15, 2015-01-01, 12
1, 2015-08-15, 3000-01-01, 2017-08-01, 24
```

To bring some context to these numbers:

- SubID is the id of the customer
- StardDT is the start date of the record
- EndDT is the end date of the record
- ContractEndDT is the end date of the contract
- ContractPeriod is the period of the contract

We need to calculate the monthly condition (MonthTowardExpiration) of the the contracts that we see in the first table.
As far as I understood, we need to return all the rows for the first contract from 2014-01-01 till the ContractEndDate - 2015-01-01 and after that there is a period that the customer doesn't have active contracts so we return negative values as -1,-2 and etc. And on the 2015-08-15 another contract starts till 2017-08-01 and we start again from 24 and descending. I have tried to do it with Recursive CTE like this:

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    -- Anchor member: Starting with the initial row from the Contracts table
    SELECT
        SubID,
        DATEADD(MONTH, -ContractPeriod, ContractEndDT) AS FromDT,
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -ContractPeriod, ContractEndDT)) AS ToDT,
        ContractEndDT,
        ContractPeriod,
        DATEDIFF(MONTH,StartDT,ContractEndDT) as MonthTowardExpiration 
    FROM Contracts
    WHERE SubID = 1
        AND StartDT = (SELECT MIN(StartDT) FROM Contracts WHERE SubID = 1) 

UNION ALL

-- Recursive member: Generating subsequent rows based on the previous row
SELECT
    SubID,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT) AS FromDT,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT)) AS ToDT,
    ContractEndDT,
    ContractPeriod,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT) > ContractEndDT THEN 0
        ELSE MonthTowardExpiration - 1 -- Decrement MonthTowardExpiration
    END AS MonthTowardExpiration
FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT) <= ContractEndDT
)
SELECT SubID, FromDT, ToDT, ContractEndDT, ContractPeriod, MonthTowardExpiration
--into #temp
FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY FromDT;
```

But I cannot include the logic about the period in which there is no active contract and also the rows for the second contract. I hope my words makes sense. Gladly will respond to further questions.

Follow up:

I managed to get all the rows for both contracts except the ones that are negative(when the customer does not have any contracts active)

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    -- Anchor member: Starting with the initial row from the Contracts table
    SELECT
        SubID,
        DATEADD(MONTH, -ContractPeriod, ContractEndDT) AS FromDT,
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -ContractPeriod, ContractEndDT)) AS ToDT,
        ContractEndDT,
        ContractPeriod,
        DATEDIFF(MONTH,StartDT,ContractEndDT) as MonthTowardExpiration 
    FROM Contracts
    WHERE SubID = 1
        AND StartDT = (SELECT MIN(StartDT) FROM Contracts WHERE SubID = 1) 
        OR ContractEndDT = (SELECT MAX(ContractEndDT) FROM Contracts WHERE SubID = 1) 


UNION ALL

-- Recursive member: Generating subsequent rows based on the previous row
SELECT
    SubID,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT) AS FromDT,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT)) AS ToDT,
    ContractEndDT,
    ContractPeriod,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT) > ContractEndDT THEN 0
        ELSE MonthTowardExpiration - 1 -- Decrement MonthTowardExpiration
    END AS MonthTowardExpiration
FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FromDT) <= ContractEndDT
)
SELECT SubID, FromDT, ToDT, ContractEndDT, ContractPeriod, MonthTowardExpiration
--into #temp
FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY FromDT;
```

Comment: Seems everyone is asking this question today, you need to first build a query which gives you a row for each period you need, using a calendar table or constructed table, then join your results onto it.

Comment: And no, we don't want images, just data formatted as text

Comment: Okay, sorry for the images, kinda new here haha.
So I need a calendar or constructed table which includes each yyyy-mm from 2014-01-01 till 2017-08-01? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yip............

Comment: Yeah, not really sure how to integrate the constructed table in the other logic.

Comment: Normally just a join..., Your data fits certain periods, which you join it to, Eg year/month for example

Comment: Can you give me some example with code following the case?